# Matlab: Multidimensional constrained nonlinear minimization such as Nelder-Mead?

Tags: matlab, math, mathematical-optimization, minimization

I need to find the **constrained** version of fminsearch in Matlab, the fminsearch works with unconstrained nonlinear minimization. What is such operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fminbnd`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html) is a bounded non-linear minimisation function, but it is restricted to one-dimension.

[`fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) is the constrained version of fminsearch, but is only available in the Optimisation Toolbox.

If you have the Optimation toolbox, you should use `fmincon`, as it is more flexible, and in general will be faster.

Comment: Can you look there how I am setting up the options wrong with the fmincon? I am trying to test different algorithms with it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600062/matlab-how-to-set-up-fmincon-with-active-set-method.