# Matlab: syntax of the fmincon with active-set method and only inequality constraints?

Tags: matlab, math, syntax, warnings, constraints

I am trying to set up **[fmincon](http://www.mathworks.se/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html)** with the active-set method for the linear constrained minimisation problem where minimising the objective function **@fun** such that

[image]

but the trials firing odd errors more in the history.

**Trial 1**

> ```
> [x,fval]=fmincon(@fun, Guess, A, b)
> ```

**Trial 2**

> ```
> options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','active-set');
> [x,fval]=fmincon(@fun, Guess, A, b, options)
> ```

Comment: What is **exampleRHR**? You do not define it anywhere.

Comment: Can you please define the function **DijIIii**?

Comment: @Masi irrelevant, the format of DijIIii and other objective functions are determined by the fmincon manual and the function could be anything. I was able to get it working after understanding the syntax of the manual. One needs to use empty placeholders like instructed by user2816823.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong options for the algorithm. MATLAB looks at the parameters you provide and uses an algorithm that uses those parameters. It throws a warning because different algorithms can have different results (and you should never ignore these) 'trust-region-reflective' is the default algorithm for fmincon. From the documentation:

> 'trust-region-reflective' requires you to provide a gradient, and
>   allows only bounds or **linear equality constraints**, but not both.

The documentation for your call to fmincon says:

> x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b) starts at x0 and attempts to find a minimizer
>   x of the function described in fun subject to the **linear inequalities**
>   A*x ≤ b. x0 can be a scalar, vector, or matrix.

You probably intended to use

> x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq)

Where you would have A = [], b = [], and Aeq and beq be whatever you had A and b to before (if you want to use trust-region-reflective).

Your second trial did not work because you're actually calling `x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq)`. You instead try to pass an options structure.

[This page explains how to set options](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/set-and-change-options.html)

EDIT: If you want to pass options, you have to specify all the optional parameters:

```
[x,fval] = fmincon(@DijIIii,x0, A , b,[], [], [], [],@nonlcon,options);
```

Comment: I have editted my answer. If you have inequality constraints just change the options to active-set and pass it to fmincon call as I wrote.